# List of random odd numbers

Tags: python

I am trying to get a list of odd numbers between 0 and 100. The length of the list is decided by entering the number.

It should be a list of maximum of 50 elements. If user enters a higher value, the message is "error". This goes ok, but I don't get any other information when the entered value is lower than 50. I can't find the error.

`num_impares` represents the vector of the list with the odd numbers.

```
import random

elementos = int(input("how many elements should be?"))

num_impares = []
                  
if elementos > 50:
  print ("Error")

else: 
    while len (num_impares)!= elementos:
        for i in range (elementos-1):
            if random.randrange (101) %2 !=0:
                  num_impares.append(i)              
                      
print (num_impares)
```

Comment: Why do you have a `for` inside the `while`? You add too many items at each iteration so you get ***more*** than `elementos` elements so the condition `while len (num_impares)!= elementos:` is always true...

Comment: In addition to that instead of generating numbers under 100 and checking if odd it would be easier to generate below 50(say x) and store 2x+1

Answer (score 1):

I just suggest you to learn `itertools` module.

```py
import itertools
import random


def odd_generator(start=0, end=99):
    while True:
        # you could implement more advanced logic here
        x = random.randint(start, end)
        yield x | 1


nums_count = 50
res = list(itertools.islice(odd_generator(), nums_count))
print(len(res), res)
assert len(res) == nums_count
assert all(x % 2 == 1 for x in res)
```

Comment: To shorten your expression, it can simply be `yield x | 1` ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
import random

elementos = int(input("how many elements should be?"))

num_impares = []
                  
if elementos > 50:
  print ("Error")

else: 
    num_impares=[2*random.randrange (49)+1 for i in range( elementos)]              
                      
print (num_impares)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use `!=`, instead, use `<=` or `<`. Also, you were printing the index not the random number. Here is the fixed code:

```
import random

elementos = int(input("how many elements should be?"))

num_impares = []
                  
if elementos > 50:
  print ("Error")

else: 
    while len(num_impares) < elementos:
        randnum = random.randrange(101)
        if randnum %2 !=0:
              num_impares.append(randnum)              
                      
print (num_impares)
```